# Challenging Cubic Conundrum

Tags: polynomials, cubics

> Let the real roots of the polynomial $P(x) = x^3-6x^2+3x+1$ be $a,b,c $ . Then , find the possible values of $a^2b+b^2c+c^2a$ .

The answer is ${{-3,24}}$ . I’ve tried transformation , and algebraic manipulation , but nothing seems to work . I also found it interesting that the quantity equalling -3 implies $\sum \frac{a}{b} = 3$ , the equality case of the rearrangement inequality . Can someone shed some light on this as well ?

Comment: That's because the expression $a^2b + b^2c + c^2a$ has symmetric group $A_3$, which has index $2$ in the whole permutation group $S_3$. Therefore there are $2$ possible answers.

Comment: One way could be to call $A=a^2b+b^2c+c^2a$ and $B=a^2c+c^2b+b^2a$. Then $A+B$ and $AB$ are symmetric functions on the roots $a,b,c$ and therefore are polynomials on $a+b+c=6, ab+bc+ac=3, abc=-1$, given by the coefficients of the polynomial. Once you have the values of $A+B$ and $AB$, you can compute the values of $A$ by solving the quadratic system of equations.

Comment: @WhatsUp Do you have a reference or name for that result? I know the standard result on symmetric polynomials, but that is a really nice generalisation!