# If $a$, $b$, $c$ are the roots of $x^3-6x^2+3x+1=0$, find all possible values of $a^2b+b^2c+c^2a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, cubics

> Let $a$, $b$, $c$ be the roots of
> $$x^3 - 6x^2 + 3x + 1 = 0$$ Find all possible values of $a^2 b + b^2 c + c^2 a$. Express all the possible values, in commas.

I've already tried to bash out all the roots, Vieta's Formula, and try to manipulate the equation to become easier to work with. However, Vieta's didn't get me anywhere, and I couldn't find a way to make the equation simpler or anything. Any hints to start this problem?

Comment: Just a bit of pedantry, $a, \, b \, c$ would be the _solutions_ to the equation, but they would be the _roots_ of $y=x^3-6x^2+3x+1$.

Comment: @DUO  I think that it is fine to say "$a, b, c$ are the roots of $x^3 - 6x^2 + 3x +1 = 0$" or  "$a, b, c$ are the solutions of $x^3 - 6x^2 + 3x +1 = 0$". Usually, for $f(x)=0$ where $f(x)$ is a polynomial, we call "roots"; If $f(x)$ is not a polynomial, we call "solutions". Am I right?

Comment: @RiverLi Actually, regardless of if it's a polynomial, it's still called "solutions".

Comment: @DUO  We can always call "solutions". But if $f(x)$ is a polynomial, we may call "roots".

Comment: @RiverLi I've never head someone make that distinction.

Comment: @DUO  OK. I saw something like "roots of $x^2 - x - 1 = 0$" in many books. Is it really more often to say "roots of $y = x^2 - x - 1$" than "roots of $x^2 - x - 1 = 0$"?

Comment: @RiverLi Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112386/discussion-between-duo-and-river-li).

Comment: @DUO I think that we had better stop here.  Perhaps some other users would give comments.

Comment: By chance, I found the same question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3408841/challenging-cubic-conundrum

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint : Let $A=a^2 b + b^2 c + c^2 a$ and $B=a^2 c + b^2 a + c^2 b$. Now calculate $A+B$ and $AB$.

> Now consider the quadratic whose roots are $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Ok, I've gotten their sum is $a^2 c + b^2 a + c^2 b + a^2 b + b^2 c + c^2 a$ and their product is $a^4 b c + a^3 b^3 + a^3 c^3 + 3 a^2 b^2 c^2 + a b^4 c + a b c^4 + b^3 c^3.$ I'm not sure how to use the spoiler, though.

Comment: I'm still not sure how this helps me, could you elaborate?

Comment: @FrostBite The two expressions are symmetric polynomials in $a$, $b$ and $c$. Express them in terms of the elementary symmetric polynomials in $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Comment: Just as a check for your answer; the coefficients of the polynomial are integers and its Galois group is $A_3$, so the possible values should be two integers.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you so much, I understand how this hint helps now!

Answer (score 4):

Let $p = a + b + c$, $q = ab + bc + ca$ and $r = abc$.

As pointed out by @Donald Splutterwit, we may let $A = a^2b + b^2c + c^2a$ and $B = ab^2 + bc^2 + ca^2$,
then $A + B$ and $AB$ are both symmetric which can both be expressed in terms of polynomials of $p, q, r$.
Indeed, we have
\begin{align} 
A + B &= a^2b + b^2c + c^2a + ab^2 + bc^2 + ca^2\\
&= a^2(b+c) + b^2(c+a) + c^2(a+b)\\
&= (a^2+b^2+c^2)(a+b+c) - (a^3 + b^3 + c^3)\\
&= (p^2 - 2q)p - [3r + p(p^2 - 2q - q)]\\
&= pq - 3r
\end{align}
where we have used the known identity
$$a^3 + b^3 + c^3 - 3abc = (a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2 - ab - bc - ca).$$
Also, we have
\begin{align}
AB &= (a^3+b^3+c^3)abc + (a^3b^3 + b^3c^3 + c^3a^3) + 3(abc)^2\\
&= [3r + p(p^2 - 2q - q)]r + [q^3 - 6r^2 - 3r(pq - 3r)] + 3r^2\\
&= p^3r-6pqr+q^3+9r^2
\end{align}
where we have used
\begin{align}
(ab+bc+ca)^3 &= a^3b^3 + b^3c^3 + c^3a^3 + 6(abc)^2\\
&\quad + 3abc(a^2b + b^2c + c^2a + ab^2 + bc^2 + ca^2).
\end{align}

Now, by Vieta's formula, we have $p = 6, q = 3, r = -1$.
Thus, $A + B = 21$ and $AB = -72$ which results in $A = 24, B = -3$ or $A = -3, B = 24$.
Thus, all the possible values of $A$ are $24, -3$.