# If p, q, r are the roots of $x^3-6x^2+3x+1=0$ determine the possible values of $p^2q+q^2r+pr^2$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, cubics

If p, q, r are the roots of $x^3-6x^2+3x+1=0$ determine the possible values of $p^2q+q^2r+pr^2$. I tried to solve this problem through Vieta's relations but I did not find a way that allows not to use the cubic formula.
I found this question on Pathfinder of Olympiad Mathematics and I have been struggling for a week without getting anywhere.

Comment: Can you not write $x^3 - 6x^2 + 3x + 1$ as $(x-p)(x-q)(x-r)$, expand and compare coefficients?

Comment: Your question has already been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3805574/if-a-b-c-are-the-roots-of-x3-6x23x1-0-find-all-possible-values-of).

Answer (score 6):

Hint: Let
\begin{eqnarray*}
A=p^2q+q^2r+r^2p \\
B=pq^2+qr^2+rp^2.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now calculate $A+B$ and $AB$ ... and solve the quadratic.

Comment: I found this hint a bit "magic" at first. It was more natural to me after computing $(p+q+r)(pq+qr+rp) = A+B+3pqr$. I started posting this as a separate answer, but couldn't actually finish without using your trick with the quadratic :-)

Comment: @Donald Splutterwit but why there's need for B and also when we will get values we will also get value of B which is not needed right ?

Comment: @Ash_Blanc Have a little think about what happens when you permute the values $p,q$ and $r$. There are two values for $A$ ... & $B$ will be the other one.