Let $a,b,c$ are real number and $a+b+c=2$, $ab+bc+ca=1$. Find min and max of $P=a^2b+b^2c+c^2a$
Let $a,b,c$ are real number and $a+b+c=2$, $ab+bc+ca=1$. Find min and max of $P=a^2b+b^2c+c^2a$
Maybe $(a+b+c)^2 = (a^2 + b^2 + c^2) + 2ab + 2bc + 2ca$, $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 2$ is useful. I proved $a^3 +b^3 + c^3 \ge a^2b + b^2c + c^2a$ using AM-GM but it's wrong because a, b, c are real number. Any hints?

The fact that the premises have a specific form seems awful coincidental to me.  My approach, which might fail, would be to therefore consult Vieta's formulas to try get some general sense of the format of a polynomial equation that has $~a,b,c~$ as its roots.

Please see this article on MathSE protocol.

Maybe $4=(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+bc+ca)=a^2+b^2+c^2+2,$ so  $a^2+b^2+c^2=2$ is useful. It helped me simplify some equations when I tried Lagrange multiplers, but still got messy.

Let $p = a + b + c = 2, q = ab + bc + ca = 1, r = abc$.
Let $Q = ab^2 + bc^2 + ca^2$.
Then $P + Q = pq - 3r = 2 - 3r$, and $P - Q = (a-b)(b-c)(a-c)$.
We have $(a - b)^2 = (a + b)^2 - 4ab
= (a+b)^2 - 4[1 - c(a + b)]$
$= (2 - c)^2 - 4[1 - c(2 - c)] = c(4 - 3c)$.
Similarly, $(b - c)^2 = a(4 - 3a)$ and $(c - a)^2 = b(4 - 3b)$.
Thus, we have
$$(a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2
= abc (4 - 3a)(4 - 3b)(4 - 3c) = 
r(4 - 27r).$$
(1) For minimum
We have
\begin{align*}
 P &= \frac{P + Q}{2} + \frac{P-Q}{2}\\
 &= 1 - \frac{3r}{2} + \frac12 (a-b)(b-c)(a-c)\\
 &\ge 1 - \frac{3r}{2} - \frac12\sqrt{(a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2}\\
 &= 1 - \frac{3r}{2} - \frac12\sqrt{4r - 27r^2}\\
 &\ge \frac23.
\end{align*}
(Note: When $r = 1/9$, $1 - \frac{3r}{2} - \frac12\sqrt{4r - 27r^2} = \frac23$.)
On the other hand, we have $P = 2/3$
when $b \ge a \ge c$ are the three real roots
of $u^3 - 2u^2 + u - 1/9 = 0$.
It admits a simple form as follows:
$a = \frac23 + \frac23\cos \frac{5\pi}{9},
b = \frac23 + \frac23\cos \frac{\pi}{9},
c = \frac23 + \frac23\cos \frac{7\pi}{9}$.
Thus, the minimum is $2/3$.
(2) For maximum
We have
\begin{align*}
 P &= \frac{P + Q}{2} + \frac{P-Q}{2}\\
 &= 1 - \frac{3r}{2} + \frac12 (a-b)(b-c)(a-c)\\
 &\le 1 - \frac{3r}{2} + \frac12\sqrt{(a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2}\\
 &= 1 - \frac{3r}{2} + \frac12\sqrt{4r - 27r^2}\\
 &\le \frac{10}{9}.
\end{align*}
(Note: When $r = 1/27$, $1 - \frac{3r}{2} - \frac12\sqrt{4r - 27r^2} = \frac{10}{9}$.)
On the other hand, we have $P = 10/9$
when $a \ge b \ge c$ are the three real roots
of $u^3 - 2u^2 + u - 1/27 = 0$.
It admits a simple form as follows: $a = \frac23 + \frac23\cos \frac{2\pi}{9},
b = \frac23 + \frac23\cos \frac{4\pi}{9},
c = \frac23 + \frac23\cos \frac{8\pi}{9}$.
Thus, the maximum is $10/9$.

Let $x=a^2b+b^2c+c^2a$ and $y=ab^2+bc^2+ca^2$ and $z=abc$
so $$x+y = (ab+bc+ca)(a+b+c) - 3abc = 2 - 3z$$
$$xy=(a^3+b^3+c^3)abc +a^3b^3+b^3c^3+c^3a^3+3a^2b^2c^2$$
$$=(ab+bc+ca)^3-3abc(ab+bc+ca)(a+b+c)+3a^2b^2c^2+abc[(a+b+c)^2-3(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)+3abc]+3a^2b^2c^2=9z^2-4z+1$$
So $x,y$ is solutions to equation:
$$t^2-(2-3z)t+9z^2-4z+1$$
$$\Delta=4z-27z^2$$
$$\Delta \ge0 \iff 4z-27z^2 \ge 0 \iff 0 \le z\le \frac{4}{27}$$
so
$$x,y=\frac{2-3z\pm \sqrt{4z-2yz^2}}{2}$$
Min: Prove
$$A=\frac{2-3z - \sqrt{4z-27z^2}}{2} \ge \frac{2}{3}$$
Max: Prove
$$B=\frac{2-3z + \sqrt{4z-27z^2}}{2} \le \frac{10}{9}$$

Nice. When I saw your idea, I just remembered that some years ago I did similar thing for some question. I searched it. It is this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3805574/if-a-b-c-are-the-roots-of-x3-6x23x1-0-find-all-possible-values-of/3805738#3805738
